# preserve html content when parsing xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file

```
<text>
    <defalut>This file has the following features:</defalut>
    <value>
        <ul>
            <li><info>CSS text formatting </info></li>
            <li><info>Text loaded from a XML</info></li>
            <li><info>Scrolls with easing</info></li>
            <li><info>Mouse wheel supported</info></li>
            <li><info>HTML supported</info></li>
            <li><info>Click on the bar to move  the handle to that point</info></li>
            <li><info>Supports images</info></li>
            <li><info>The scrollbar hides if not needed</info></li>
            <li><info>The scrollbar resizes proportonal to the text sizeq</info></li>
        </ul>
    </value>
    <tittle>Lorem Ipsum</tittle>
</text>
```

I am using xpath and xquery to parse this file

```
$xml_str1 = file_get_contents("file.xml");
echo $xml_str = $xml_str.$xml_str1;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//text');
```

but iam getting the string only.
How can i preserve the html tags in the result
 if iam parsing `<value>` tag i am getting the content without `<ul>` and `<li>` How can i get the full html content in the `<value>` tag as it is

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use asXML(), SimpleXMLElement::asXML — Return a well-formed XML string based on SimpleXML element

```
$result = $xml->xpath('//text');
echo $result[0]->asXML();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//text/value');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not %100  certain I follow your problem, but my gut tells me that you're looking for a CDATA section:

```
<text>
    <defalut>This file has the following features:</defalut>
    <value>
    <![CDATA[
        <ul>
            <li><info>CSS text formatting </info></li>
            <li><info>Text loaded from a XML</info></li>
            <li><info>Scrolls with easing</info></li>
            <li><info>Mouse wheel supported</info></li>
            <li><info>HTML supported</info></li>
            <li><info>Click on the bar to move  the handle to that point</info></li>
            <li><info>Supports images</info></li>
            <li><info>The scrollbar hides if not needed</info></li>
            <li><info>The scrollbar resizes proportonal to the text size</info></li>
        </ul>
    ]]>
    </value>
    <tittle>Lorem Ipsum</tittle>
</text>
```

Or you could escape all those `<` and `>` characters:

```
<text>
    <defalut>This file has the following features:</defalut>
    <value>
        &lt;ul&gt;
            &lt;li&gt;&lt;info&gt;CSS text formatting &lt;/info&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
            &lt;li&gt;&lt;info&gt;Text loaded from a XML&lt;/info&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
            &lt;li&gt;&lt;info&gt;Scrolls with easing&lt;/info&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
            &lt;li&gt;&lt;info&gt;Mouse wheel supported&lt;/info&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
            &lt;li&gt;&lt;info&gt;HTML supported&lt;/info&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
            &lt;li&gt;&lt;info&gt;Click on the bar to move  the handle to that point&lt;/info&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
            &lt;li&gt;&lt;info&gt;Supports images&lt;/info&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
            &lt;li&gt;&lt;info&gt;The scrollbar hides if not needed&lt;/info&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
            &lt;li&gt;&lt;info&gt;The scrollbar resizes proportonal to the text size&lt;/info&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
        &lt;/ul&gt;
    </value>
    <tittle>Lorem Ipsum</tittle>
</text>
```

Comment: when i tried 
$xml_str1 = file_get_contents($file);
$xml_str = $xml_str.$xml_str1;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//text');
am getting the result
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [defalut] => This file has the following features:
            [value] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [tittle] => Lorem Ipsum
        )

)

Comment: I used first solution with CDATA

Answer (score 0):

Once you parse the file, it gets loaded into a DOM representation, which is an in-memory tree of *all* the nodes.  To get the HTML back you have to serialize the node containing the XML.

Answer (score 0):

No need of CDATA
WE can simply use

```
$result = $xml->xpath('//text');
echo $result[0]->asXML();
```

It will load the HTML content as it is